# Broken Images in Media Manager in Wordpress 4.7

Tags: wordpress, image, media

We had an issue on our server which resulted in our entire 'wp-content' directory getting deleted.

We restored the themes, plugins and some of the images but we're now left with allot of broken images in the media library. We cannot re-upload and fix all of these broken images as the majority were generated from a feed which uses unique filenames etc..

Screenshot: [image: http://c2n.me/3GbrLIa.png]

My question is simply, how do I quickly and easily remove all the broken images from the media library? They are obviously in the database and I just need to remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files itself are still exist in the server with their original names in the time you uploaded them so you just need to generate again the thumbnails and there is a plugin called Regenerate Thumbnails that allow you to do it simply within a click.

If the files was restored without their original names, it will be actually impossible to recover them automatically because the system donesn't able to attach the uploaded files to the posts they was attached before.

You will have to delete all images that not linked to actual files and for now you will have to do it manullay because there is no plugin (at least not in WordPress repository) that offer this functionality. There is a plugin that called "Broken Images" that it's not updated for 2 years. I will not recommend to use it. I also searched for a plugin with some functionality but I didn't found and decided to develope it by myself. I'm going to release this plugin soon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The files do not exist any more and there is no backup. Regenerate Thumbnails won't work. Indeed as you said, the 'links' are in WP but the files are not. Seems I'll have to manually delete all the images but If you are developing a plugin I would love to test it!